# is there any way to sort a vector of pair with according to user?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector, std-pair

**I want to sort the vector of pair according to second of pair in descending order but when the second will be same value for two or more elements then sorting will be done in basis of first in pair**

I had implemented the sorting in descending order according to second but with same values of second it simply maintain its order , I want to sort the similar elements of second according to first in descending order .
'''

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<long long int,long long int> &a,const pair<long long int,long long int> &b){
        return a.second>b.second;
}
int main()
{
    vector<pair<long long int,long long int> >v;
    long long int n,i,temp,s;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>s;
        cin>>temp;
        v.push_back(make_pair(s,temp));
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\n\n";
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),sortbysecdesc);
    for(i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        cout<<v[i].first<<" "<<v[i].second<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

'''

```
Input :
999 100
1001 100
1002 100
1003 100
1004 50
1005 -50
1006 -50
1007 50
Expected Output :
1003 100
1002 100
1001 100
999 100
1007 50
1004 50
1006 -50
1005 -50
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing (for example, I'm not sure what 'with according to user' means or if/how the user interaction is a factor). But, it sounds like you just want a lexicographical sorting based on the `second` and `first` fields of the pairs. Assuming that's what you want, are you asking how to implement that?

Comment: Yeah according to user means a sorting in descending order with the second part of the pair , but if the second part pf pair have the same values in vector then it sort according to its first part of pair in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
bool MyFancySort(const pair<long long int,long long int>& a,
                 const pair<long long int,long long int>& b) {
  return std::make_tuple(-a.second, a.first) < std::make_tuple(-b.second, b.first);
}

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), MyFancySort);
```

**EDIT:** It was not originally clear that you wanted the first component in descending order, too. In that case:

```
bool MyFancySort(const pair<long long int,long long int>& a,
                 const pair<long long int,long long int>& b) {
  return std::make_tuple(a.second, a.first) > std::make_tuple(b.second, b.first);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? What happens when you try?

Comment: Ah, you want the first component to be sort in descending order, too. Then make it `return std::make_tuple(a.second, a.first) > std::make_tuple(b.second, b.first);`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<long long int,long long int> &a,const pair<long long int,long long int> &b){
        if (a.second == b.second) {
            return a.first > b.first
        }
        return a.second > b.second;
}
```